# Command-line audio player that accepts PCM over STDIO in Windows

Tags: windows, audio

Is there a command line audio player in Windows that will take a PCM stream in via STDIO and output to a sound card?  I'm hoping to find something that accepts a sample rate, bit depth, endianess, buffer size, and sound card name, then outputs audio accordingly.

It's too bad that FFmpeg audio output doesn't seem to work under Windows, as it would be perfect.